# What is the effect of doing "mv my_file .."?

Tags: files, mv

I've tried to move a file to an upper directory but I forgot the final slash `/` and now I can't find it.

What exactly have I done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash is irrelevant. Your file will be in the parent directory:

```
$ ls
file
$ mv file ..
$ ls
$ ls ../
bar  file
```

I have no idea why you don't find it. Perhaps you just missed it? Or maybe it's a hidden file (name begins with a dot) and you need `ls -a` to see it.

Comment: It apperaed... but in the parent of the parent directory! I'm thinking that it is due to the parent directory is a symbolic link. Could be? I don't know. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @LuisDíaz yes. Symbolic links act strangely, it depends on how you accessed the daughter directory. Try this: `cd linkToDir; pwd` and compare to `cd targetOfLink; pwd`.